# Help to restore integer function by values

Tags: functions

I have written a piece of code which produces binary masks for unrelated algorithm and have found that the only dependent value is mask's index. Here is a list of first 32 values in the form of

```
x: binary y (decimal y)
```

:

```
0:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000000000001    (1)
1:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000000000011    (3)
2:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000000000100    (4)
3:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000000001111    (15)
4:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000000010000    (16)
5:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000000110000    (48)
6:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000001000000    (64)
7:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000011111111    (255)
8:  Binary: 00000000000000000000000100000000    (256)
9:  Binary: 00000000000000000000001100000000    (768)
10: Binary: 00000000000000000000010000000000    (1024)
11: Binary: 00000000000000000000111100000000    (3840)
12: Binary: 00000000000000000001000000000000    (4096)
13: Binary: 00000000000000000011000000000000    (12288)
14: Binary: 00000000000000000100000000000000    (16384)
15: Binary: 00000000000000001111111111111111    (65535)
16: Binary: 00000000000000010000000000000000    (65536)
17: Binary: 00000000000000110000000000000000    (196608)
18: Binary: 00000000000001000000000000000000    (262144)
19: Binary: 00000000000011110000000000000000    (983040)
20: Binary: 00000000000100000000000000000000    (1048576)
21: Binary: 00000000001100000000000000000000    (3145728)
22: Binary: 00000000010000000000000000000000    (4194304)
23: Binary: 00000000111111110000000000000000    (16711680)
24: Binary: 00000001000000000000000000000000    (16777216)
25: Binary: 00000011000000000000000000000000    (50331648)
26: Binary: 00000100000000000000000000000000    (67108864)
27: Binary: 00001111000000000000000000000000    (251658240)
28: Binary: 00010000000000000000000000000000    (268435456)
29: Binary: 00110000000000000000000000000000    (805306368)
30: Binary: 01000000000000000000000000000000    (1073741824)
```

Is it possible to write an integer function which returns y by x?

1. For every even x, y is equal to 2 in power of x...

Comment: Lagrangian interpolation says no finite list is enough to do that.

Comment: @Grief Google for 'polynomial interpolation'.

Comment: I believe that the form of that function won't be polynomial.

Comment: @Grief There's always a polynomial that passes through the points $(x,y)$ you're given. Whether it's good enough for your purposes or not, is a different matter.

Comment: @Git Gud You are correct, but this is not the complete list of points, just first 31 values. Maybe it would be more helpful in binary form (I have updated the question)

Comment: There's a pattern in there, but the role of the values at 7, 15, and 23 is not clear.  Can you post the values for 31, 39, 47?